# Rails 5 CarrierWave error "nil is not a valid asset source"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, carrierwave

Im getting an error "nil is not a valid asset source" when I got to the show page in my app. I'm not sure If it the image is just not saving or how I am attempting to display it is wrong.

Uploader folder:

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

storage :file

 def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
 end
```

Profile Model:

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :albums

  mount_uploader :image, AvatarUploader
end
```

Schema:

```
 create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.date     "born"
  t.string   "bio"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string   "image"
 end
```

The Field from the View where the images gets uploaded:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 def index
  @search = Profile.search(params[:q])
  @profiles = @search.result(distinct: true)
 end

 def show
 end

 def new
  @profile = Profile.new
 end

 def edit
 end

 def create
  @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)

  respond_to do |format|
  if @profile.save format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was  successfully       created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @profile }
   else
     format.html { render :new }
     format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status:  :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def update
 respond_to do |format|
  if @profile.update(profile_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @profile }
   else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
   end
  end

 def destroy
  @profile.destroy
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to profile_url, notice: 'Profile was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private

def set_profile
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
end

 def profile_params
  params.require(:profile).permit(:name, :bio, :born)
 end    
end
```

The Form View That I fill out and add the Picture and Info:

```
<%= form_for @profile, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
<% if @profile.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@profile.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this profile from being saved:</h2>
  <ul>
  <% @profile.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <% end %>

<div class="field">
 <%= f.file_field :image %><br>
</div>

<div class="field">
 <%= f.label :name %><br>
 <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<br>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :bio %><br>
<%= f.text_area :bio %>
</div>
<br>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :born %><br>
<%= f.date_select :born %>
</div>
<br>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
```

And the Show view where I get the error:

```
<p>
<%= image_tag @profile.image_url %>
</p>

<p>
<strong>Name:</strong>
<%= @profile.name %>
</p>

<p>
<strong>Bio:</strong>
<%= @profile.bio %>
</p>

<p>
<strong>Born:</strong>
<%= @profile.born %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_profile_path(@profile) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', profiles_path %>
```

I submit the image and get the error message with the line from the show view above highlighted.

"Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/music-db/app/views/profiles/show.html.erb where line #5 raised:

nil is not a valid asset source"

From reading other similar issues. It us maybe that the image is not saving correctly. As if there was image save it would not be nil. But really I am just not sure. Am only trying out this gem for the first time.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes your image is not stored ..can you paste whole view form and controller method's ?

Comment: I have added the full view form and show plus the controller. Hopefully that enough to make sense. Adding the "unless @profile.image.blank?" as suggest by Askanksha below does make the a default picture show up, but it doesn't help me actually store and the display the image I want to show.

Comment: have you installed gem 'mini_magick' ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your method to accpet image param well

```
 def profile_params
  params.require(:profile).permit(:name, :bio, :born)
 end
```

to

```
 def profile_params
  params.require(:profile).permit(:name, :bio, :born, :image)
 end
```

As well check you should install `gem 'mini_magick'`

Comment: Haha, Just before you posted this, I spotted the mistake. Thanks for help WishZone. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This means that your image field is blank right now. In other words, it is nil and doesn't have the name of the field stored in it. To prevent the error, check if the image is present first.

```
<p>
  <%= image_tag @profile.image_url if @profile.image.present? %>
</p>
```

or

```
<p>
   <%= image_tag @profile.image_url unless @profile.image.blank? %>
</p>
```

I haven't checked it but either of the two shall work for you.

Comment: Hey, This does help me display a default image for when the picture wont show. But I think the problem is the image is not saving for me, so the default show each time. Thank you for that extra bit all the same. It is useful and I will add it to my code. But it doesn't fully solve the problem I have of the image not saving.

Answer (score 0):

While adding in all the extra code I just noticed that in my private profile params I never added the image in. So because of the strong parameters it wasn't letting me save the picture. If that makes sense.

Thanks to both of you for your help.